# use react in views folder in mvc express project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a task to create a form to fill into the request details using react.js using mvc pattern in express.js project

this is file structure in the project

```
 +-- app.js
 +-- controller
 |   +-- indexController.js
 +-- routes
 |   +-- index.js
 |   +-- indexRouter.js
 +-- views
 |   +-- index.jsx
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      drug: '',
      disease:'',
      type:''
    };
  }

  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const { drug , disease , type } = this.state
    return (
      <form>
      <p>Drug</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="drug"
        value={drug}
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />


      <p>Disease</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="disease"
        value={disease}
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />



      <p>Type</p>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="type"
        value={type}
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default MyForm
```

**routers/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const indexRouter = require('./indexRouter');

router.use('/', indexRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

**routers/indexRouter.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const { getIndexData } = require('../controllers/indexController');

router.get('/', getIndexData);

module.exports = router;
```

**indexControllers.js**

```
// Controller for all root / routes

module.exports = {
  getIndexData(req, res) {
    //return res.render('index.html');
    res.sendfile('index');
  },
};
```

and when run the project i get this error

> Blockquote
>   Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: i inserted all codes

Comment: Where is your app.js file ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're really wanting to use React to render your Express views, you will need to use `ReactDomServer.renderToString` (or one of the other server-render libraries - you can also render to stream or DOM, but `renderToString` is the most common)

Your controller should import/require ReactDomServer:

```
var ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
```

Then you'd import/require your index view:

```
var indexView = require('../path/to/index'); // I'd recommend renaming your view to index.js so you don't have to use webpack to handle *.jsx files
```

Finally, have your controller method return

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(indexView);
```

Express doesn't understand React rendering as one of its view rendering technologies (like handlebars or ejs). Since React is just javascript, you'll need to use a method that understands all the intricacies of its system.